# Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express does not automatically find texture file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xna, textures, monogame

I'm using Visual C# 2010 Express and Monogame to build files for use with a game.
Yesterday when I loaded a .x file it automatically found and added the texture file to the project.

Now it isn't finding the texture automatically, and if I manually locate the file it builds it twice.

Please help.

Edit: I've tried reinstalling both monogame and Visual C# Express, but that doesn't fix it.

Comment: Are you trying to add it to your game project or Content project?

Answer (score 0):

It still isn't finding them automatically, like it was before.
But I was able to set the texture file to "none" under build action.